# Only override parts of style

Tags: react-native

I have this component:

```
const RegularTextInput: FunctionComponent<TextInputProps> = (props) => {
    const { colors } = useTheme();

    return (
        <TextInput
            style={{
                fontFamily: 'Poppins-Light',
                backgroundColor: colors.textFieldBackground,
                height: 40,
                padding: 5,
                borderRadius: 10,
                overflow: 'hidden',
                lineHeight: 21,
                fontSize: 14,
                borderColor: colors.primary,
                borderWidth: 1,
                width: 180,
            }}
            {...props}
        ></TextInput>
    );
};

export default RegularTextInput;
```

When I use the component, I would like to add some styling:

```
<RegularTextInput
    style={{
      marginRight: 10,
      marginLeft: 10,
    }}
/>
```

But this totally overwrites the entire style, how can I add single style parameters or override some style parameters of my componenet while preserving the rest of the style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all about the order of props. Define the default props always first and then custom ones.

```
const RegularTextInput: FunctionComponent<TextInputProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      style={[{
          fontFamily: 'Poppins-Light',
...
          width: 180,
      }, props.style]}>
    </TextInput>
  );
};

<RegularTextInput
  style={{
    borderColor: 'pink',
    width: '100%'          
  }}
  onChangeText={console.log}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your `RegularTextInput`'s default style with what style you want to add like this:

```js
const RegularTextInput: FunctionComponent<TextInputProps> = (props) => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  return (
    <TextInput
      style={[
        {
          fontFamily: "Poppins-Light",
          backgroundColor: colors.textFieldBackground,
          height: 40,
          padding: 5,
          borderRadius: 10,
          overflow: "hidden",
          lineHeight: 21,
          fontSize: 14,
          borderColor: colors.primary,
          borderWidth: 1,
          width: 180,
        },
        props.style,
      ]}
      {...props}
    ></TextInput>
  );
};

export default RegularTextInput;
```

Comment: All my style still gets overwritten by the user/caller of RegularTextInput. How should I use the RegularTextInput in a way so that it does not overwrite all the style?